# Get version of boot file

Tags: systemd, systemd-boot

I'm trying to figure out how **systemd-boot** determines the version of its boot file. In my current setup (all VMs), I'm running **Debian 10**, **Fedora 34**, and **Manjaro 21.0.7**, all using the same bootloader. As a test, I used `sudo bootctl update` on Fedora, installing its version of the boot file. When I later boot into Manjaro, everything works.

What I'm curious about is how my other OS's are detecting that the boot file is from Fedora 34. Here's a snippet from `bootctl status`:

```
$ bootctl status
System:
     Firmware: UEFI 2.31 (VMware, Inc. 1.00)
  Secure Boot: disabled
   Setup Mode: user
 TPM2 Support: no
 Boot into FW: supported

Current Boot Loader:
      Product: systemd-boot v248.3-1.fc34
```

I get this same output regardless of the OS I'm running. How does `bootctl` know what the version of the systemd-boot file is?

Answer (score 1):

Systemd-boot is systemd-boot regardless of which Linux distribution you are running. Systemd-boot is a relatively simple chooser application that is not customized by the distro maker. The version of system-boot shipped by Fedora, which is currently installed on your machine is also capable of booting Manjaro, Debian, and even Windows if you want.

When systemd-boot is updated the files are taken from the distro that is currently running. The bootctl program examines the installed version of systemd-boot and only updates if the available version is newer than the installed version. The version is determined by examining the actual file, not the file name. More precisely, the version is determined by searching for the string `#### LoaderInfo: systemd-boot NNN ####` in the systemd-boot binary file, where `NNN` is a three digit version number.

Comment: Your last statement is what I'm trying to figure out: *How* is the version determined? The filename is the same on all distros, at least the 4 I've tried so far.

Comment: @ajgringo619 See my edit.

Comment: `LoaderInfo` is correct, but the more accurate place to look is here: `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/LoaderInfo-4a67b082-0a4c-41cf-b6c7-440b29bb8c4f`. Your answer got me on the right track, so thank you for that! I had tried searching the files in this directory, but nothing I grepped for showed any hits.